# Find Roots of $x^3-7$ Relative to Roots of Unity and $\sqrt{7}$

Tags: complex-analysis

find roots of $$x^3-7$$ relative to roots of unity and $\sqrt[3]7$

---

one root is $\sqrt[3]7$, remaining roots might be something like 
$$\sqrt[3]7,(\sqrt[3]7)^2w,(\sqrt[3]7)^3w $$

where $w=e^{i 2 \pi/3 }$ [and wolram alpha is sayin $x_1=-\sqrt[3]{7},x_2 = \sqrt[3]{7},x_3=(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{7}$ ]

---

*Appreciate confirmation, whether this is wrong. or more elaboration. Trying to work out a problem in abstract algebra but my complex analysis is a bit rusted. Thanks.*

Comment: Check out DeMoivre's Theorem. You will have one real root and two complex roots and the magnitude and sign will be determined by the cosine for the real part, the sine for the imaginary part.

Comment: You don't want to raise $\sqrt[3]7$ to the powers 1,2,or 3.  ($|\sqrt[3]7| \ne 1$ and the magnitude will not stay constant).  I the roots of unity that are to the powers.  So $|\omega| = 1$ so $\omega$ is a complex number  so that raising it to $k$ will "swing it round a circle" and if we swing it 3 times you get back to $1$.  To get all the roots of unity are $1, \omega, \omega^2$.  If those were made larger $r, r*\omega, r\omega^2$ the raising them to the third power will have all $\omega^k$ "swing" to $1$ and the $r$ will "grow" to $r^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $\sqrt[3]{7},\sqrt[3]{7}\omega,\sqrt[3]{7}\omega^{2}$, where $\omega$ is the third root of unity, which is $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\begin{align}x^3-a^3&=(x-a)(x-a\omega)(x-a\omega^2)\end{align}$$

where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of unity are $1, \omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega = e^{i\frac 23 \pi}$

So $(1)^3, (\omega)^3, (\omega^2)^3$ all equal $1$.

So $(\sqrt[3]{7})^3,(\omega*\sqrt[3]{7})^3,(\omega^2*\sqrt[3]{7})^3$ will all equal $7$.

So $x =  \sqrt[3]{7},\omega*\sqrt[3]{7},\omega^2*\sqrt[3]{7}$ are the three roots of $x^3 - 7 =0$.