# Let $F$ be splitting Field of $x^3 -7 \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ and let $G$ be the splitting field of $ (x^3-7) (x^2-3) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be splitting Field of $x^3 -7 \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ and let $G$ be the splitting field of 
$$ (x^3-7) (x^2-3) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

Show that $Aut(G : \mathbb{Q})$ is the product of two normal subgroups which have trivial intersection

---

I know that the roots for $$ x^3-7$$ 
are $$\sqrt[3]{7}w_3^0,\sqrt[3]{7}w_3^1,\sqrt[3]{7}w_3^2 $$

and roots for $x^2-3$ are

$$ \sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}$$

I think that that $G$ over $Q$ is of degree 6. F is normal since it splits the polynomial  and call $H$ the splitting field of the deg 2 poly. They have nothing in common and generate $G$ over $Q$

---

Another way is to find what it is in $S_6$ and show that that group has two normal subgroups that generates it.

---

*Appreciate Help. Reference where to read this subject clearly, how to solve this problem in sage,  or good examples. Thanks*

Comment: Well, I'd begin with $\;\left|\text{Gal}(G/\Bbb Q)\right|=[G:Q]\;$ ... You say you think this extension has degree $\;6\;$ , but...what is then $\;[F:\Bbb Q]\;$ , with $\;F\subset G\;$ ? BTW, I think the choice of $\;G\;$ as notation for a *field* can be slightly confusing in these cases. It'd be better, I believe, with $\;K\;$ or even $\;L\;$ . And $\;S_6\;$ most definitely has **no** two different non-trivial normal subgroups, though I think you may have meant $\;S_3\;$ instead...which also has no two non-trivial normal subgroups

Comment: Also related is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734201/find-roots-of-x3-7-relative-to-roots-of-unity-and-sqrt7). There was a similar question before, perhaps deleted now.

Comment: this question is the one that was deleted. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734389/show-that-f-not-g-in-splitting-field-of-2-polynomials-over-mathbbq

Comment: idk if it helps